React Table not Updating Automatically after CRUD Operations
I'm developing a web app using React where I have a table that displays a list of clients. The table should update automatically after performing CRUD operations on the clients. However, I'm encountering a specific issue: after adding or deleting a client, the table doesn't update automatically. It only works correctly when I edit an existing client. To make the other methods work, I have to leave the page and come back to the section.
As I mentioned, the request reaches the API and returns the expected information, but updating the table fails, even though the method is theoretically implemented.
This is my code:

  const loadClients = async () => {
    try {
      const clientsData = await SalesApi.getClients();
      const sortedClients = clientsData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      setClients(sortedClients);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching clients:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleEditClick = (client) => {
    setEditingClient(client);
  };

  const handleCancelEdit = () => {
    setEditingClient(null);
  };

  const handleSaveEdit = async (editedClient) => {
    try {
      await SalesApi.updateClient(editedClient);
      console.log('Client updated successfully:', editedClient);
      loadClients();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating client:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteClient = async (clientId) => {
    try {
      const response = await SalesApi.deleteClient(clientId);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('Client deleted successfully:', clientId);
        loadClients();
      } else {
        console.error('Error deleting client:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting client:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <MainPageContainer>
      <h1>Clients</h1>
      {(editingClient || !editingClient) && (
        <ClientsRegistrationForm
          onSubmit={async (formData) => {
            try {
              await SalesApi.addClient({
                firstName: formData.firstName,
                secondName: formData.secondName,
                firstLastName: formData.firstLastName,
                secondLastName: formData.secondLastName,
                identificationNumber: formData.identificationNumber,
                isCreditCandidate: formData.isCreditCandidate,
              });
              console.log('Client registered successfully:', formData);
              loadClients();
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error adding client:', error.message);
            }
          }}
          onCancel={handleCancelEdit}
        />
      )}
      <ClientsTable
        clients={clients}
        onEditClick={handleEditClick}
        onDeleteClick={handleDeleteClient}
        onSaveEdit={handleSaveEdit}
      />
    </MainPageContainer>
  );
};

And this is the table code:
const ClientsTable = ({ clients, onEditClick, onSaveEdit, onDeleteClick }) => {
  const cellStyles = {
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  };

 
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState(null);

  const handleEditClick = (client) => {
    setSelectedClient(client);
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
    setSelectedClient(null);
  };

  const handleEditFieldChange = (fieldName, value) => {
    setSelectedClient({
      ...selectedClient,
      [fieldName]: value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper} style={{ marginTop: '20px', margin: 'auto' }}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow style={rowStyles}>
            <TableCell style={cellStyles}>First Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell style={cellStyles}>IdNumber</TableCell>
            <TableCell style={{ ...cellStyles, textAlign: 'center' }}>Actions</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {clients.map((client, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index} style={{ background: index % 2 === 0 ? '#f9f9f9' : 'white' }}>
              <TableCell style={{ fontSize: '14px', textAlign: 'center' }}>{client.firstName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ fontSize: '14px', textAlign: 'center' }}>{client.identificationNumber}</TableCell>
 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => onEditClick(client)}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  style={{ ...buttonStyles }}
                >
                  Edit
                </Button>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => onDeleteClick(client.id)}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="secondary"
                  size="small"
                  style={{ ...buttonStyles, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
                >
                  Delete
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>

Any advice or help on how to approach this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Seems that it should be working, if you log the sortedClients inside loadClients does it show the new client / not show the deleted one?

Can you share the code of the ClientTable component?

Well, my error was due to a double request. I was sending the same request twice. Consequently, when I sent the first and original request, it didn't load properly because of the error caused by the second request. As a result, the list never updated, that's what I think. I fixed the double request and the problem seems to be solved.
Thnx btw.

@PauloFernando apparently I spoke too soon, the problem was partially solved.
the table updates when adding and editing but not when deleting, I have added the table code.

Make sure you refetch the get query of the table when the delete or update api is fetched so that new value can replace in the table
